# Python Pillow Creating an Image with List of Pixels

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I have a .txt file that contains coordinates and color codes. I want to create an image from this

My example txt file:

```
1,1#f8f3ed
1,2#fff9f1
1,3#faf2e7
1,4#fbf2e1
1,5#f6eed9
1,6#e1d6c0
1,7#e2d6be
1,8#ebdfc5
1,9#d0c4ac
1,10#cdc2ac
1,11#e3dbc6
1,12#ded7c5
.
.
187,249#1b2019
```

How can I create this image?

Edited code as below:

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageColor



path_to_file = 'data.txt'

img_data = []
height = 0
width = 0

# The first step is to read the file
with open(path_to_file) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

# Strip off new lines
lines = [x.strip('\n') for x in lines] 



for line in lines:
    x,y = line[:-7].split(',')

    # I'm assuming from the data that the x,y vals start at 1,1. Subtract 1 from each value so they are zero indexed.
    x = int(x) - 1
    y = int(y) - 1

    color = line[-7:]

    # Use PIL's ImageColor.getrgb() to convert hex string to a rgb tuple
    color = ImageColor.getrgb(color)

    img_data.append((x,y,color))


    # Keep track of the max x,y vals for to get the width and height of the image
    height = max(height, x+1)
    width = max(width, y+1)

# Create a new image
background = (0, 0, 0, 255)
img = Image.new('RGB', (width, height), background)
pixels = img.load()

# Set the pixel values from our data
for d in img_data:
    pixels[d[0], d[1]] = d[2]


img.save("image.png")
```

Now it raises:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

How to solve this error?

Comment: If you want help with this, you should post your own code attempt, and clearly explain where you're stuck. This task is fairly straight-forward, especially if the pixel list is ordered like in your example data.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageColor



path_to_file = 'test.txt'

img_data = []
height = 0
width = 0

# The first step is to read the file
with open(path_to_file) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

# Strip off new lines
lines = [x.strip('\n') for x in lines] 



for line in lines:
    x,y = line[:-7].split(',')

    # I'm assuming from the data that the x,y vals start at 1,1. Subtract 1 from each value so they are zero indexed.
    x = int(x) - 1
    y = int(y) - 1

    color = line[-7:]

    # Use PIL's ImageColor.getrgb() to convert hex string to a rgb tuple
    color = ImageColor.getrgb(color)

    img_data.append((x,y,color))


    # Keep track of the max x,y vals for to get the width and height of the image
    height = max(height, y)
    width = max(width, x)

# Create a new image
background = (0, 0, 0, 255)
img = Image.new('RGB', (width + 1, height + 1), background)
pixels = img.load()

# Set the pixel values from our data
for d in img_data:
    pixels[d[0], d[1]] = d[2]


img.save("image.png")
```

Comment: @hckn0 If you can post the actual error message I can help you better. Also, without your full data, there's no way for me to know what's wrong.